# Ansible: will it skip to next task if the current task failed

Tags: error-handling, ansible, task, skip

Since Ansible execute the tasks in order, will it skip to the next task if the current task failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in [Error handling in playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#error-handling-in-playbooks)
:

> When Ansible receives a non-zero return code from a command or a failure from a module, by default it stops executing on that host and continues on other hosts.
>
> [...]
>
> You can use `ignore_errors` to continue on in spite of the failure

Comment: Thanks Marco! Do you know if the roles are executed in order, one after another as well? And if the current role is failing will it proceed to the next role?

Answer (score 1):

From the Ansible docs:

> By default Ansible stops executing tasks on a host when a task fails on that host. You can use ignore_errors to continue on in spite of the failure.

```yml
- name: Do not count this as a failure
  ansible.builtin.command: /bin/false
  ignore_errors: yes
```

> The ignore_errors directive only works when the task is able to run and returns a value of ‘failed’. It does not make Ansible ignore undefined variable errors, connection failures, execution issues (for example, missing packages), or syntax errors.

**REFERENCES:**

Ansible docs: Error handling in playbooks: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#error-handling-in-playbooks